# Como deixar meu formulário de cadastro para o meu banco de dados seguro?

Tags: php

Ola tenho um site e uso esse seguinte formulário esse script para cadastrar projetos, mas precisa de um formulário seguro, pois se eu vou em inspecionar elemento na minha pagina e mudo o value da minha option que estava Suporte administrativo para c* ele vai salvar no meu db como c* eu queria que esse valor não tivesse como editar e tbm precisava alguma coisa para anti injection, spam e CSRF ou XSRF, mas n sei implementar pois sou muito leigo em PHP, se alguém poder ajudando com alguma dica qualquer coisa ou um script que me proteja de tudo isso agradeço

```
<?php
if(count($_POST)>0) {
    require_once("conexao.php");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO classificados (titulo, categoria, valor) VALUES ('" . $_POST["titulo"] . "','" . $_POST["categoria"] . "','" . $_POST["valor"] . "')";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $current_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    if(!empty($current_id)) {
        $message = "New User Added Successfully";
    }
}
?>
```

Uma parte do meu formulário

```
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 search-col">
<div class="input-group-addon search-category-container">
<label class="styled-select">
<select required="" class="dropdown-product selectpicker" name="categoria">
<option value="">Todas Categorias</option>
<option class="subitem" value="IT & Programacao"> IT & Programação</option>
<option value="Design e Multimedia"> Design e Multimedia</option>
<option value="Tradução e Conteúdos"> Tradução e Conteúdos</option>
<option value="Marketing e vendas"> Marketing e vendas</option>
<option value="Suporte administrativo"> Suporte administrativo</option>
<option value="Finanças de Administração"> Finanças de Administração</option>
<option value="Engenharia e Manufafuta"> Engenharia e Manufafuta</option>
<option value="Legal"> Legal</option>
</select></label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Se é muito leigo em PHP como disse na questão, e realmente precisa de um formulário seguro para uso real, seria o caso de contratar um programador, o que foge um pouco do [escopo do site](/help/on-topic). Uma simples "dica" não vai passar nem perto de resolver seu problema. Agora, enquanto estiver aprendendo, pode fazer perguntas específicas sobre partes específicas, e à medida que vai resolvendo cada etapa, pode abrir novas perguntas, mas sempre descrevendo o problema detalhadamente. Lembrando que pode sempre [edit] sua postagem para complementar (desde que não invalide respostas existentes).

Comment: Enquanto isso, pode pesquisar aqui no site sobre [SQL Injection + PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=sql+injection+php) para pegar alguns exemplos do que deve (e não deve) fazer, e também sobre [Validação + Formulário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=validação+formulário), [Senhas + Seguras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=senhas+seguras) etc.

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado pela dica e ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Como já apontaram nos comentários, o correto seria você estudar sobre segurança e como implementar isso em PHP e, caso surja alguma dúvida mais específica, perguntar aqui. 
O que podemos fazer é dar algumas dicas e você pesquisar melhor cada uma.

A primeira dica de segurança é **SEMPRE** validar os dados que chegam no seu back-end. Se você fizer isso já vai estar se prevenindo de diversos ataques. Tenha em mente que validações no front-end são apenas para melhorar a experiência do usuário.

A segunda dia é sempre verificar se o usuário tem permissão para fazer alguma operação no seu site. A forma mais fácil de fazer isso é usando session

A terceira dia é sempre escapar seus dados antes de enviar para seu banco de dados e principalmente usar um drive para conectar e fazer operações com seu banco. O PHP oferece, por exemplo o PDO.

É claro que isso não é tudo, mas é um começo. Se fiquei essas 3 coisas já vai evitar muitos ataques.

Comment: Vlw pela dica, vou dar um estuda sim